# trying to get python to randomly shuffle the list mycolours, but want python to only return 4 from the list

Tags: python, string, list, random

This is my code:

```
def main():
    mycolours = ['R', 'G', 'B', 'Y', 'P', 'O']
    myguess = 'RGBY'
    total_guess = 5
    x = random.shuffle(mycolours[:4])

    for i in range(total_guess):
        if myguess == x:
            print('CORRECT')
        else: 
            print('TRY AGAIN')
main()
```

Instead of `x` returning 4 random strings from the list it returns a value of none.

Comment: So doesn't your code work? What's your question?

Comment: And what about this question? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/33578220/how-do-i-get-python-to-randomly-return-4-letters-from-a-list

Comment: @kevinGuan No x does not return four random strings, instead it returns a value of none

Comment: So see that question, use `random.sample(mycolours, 4)` instead of `random.shuffle(mycolours[:4])`.

Comment: `random.shuffle` shuffles in place. You created a list of 4 elements, shuffled it, then discarded it.

Comment: What tdelaney said. Use `.sample` or `random.shuffle(mycolours); x = mycolours[:4]`. Note that both of these return _lists_ not strings, so you need to convert `myguess` into a list to compare it with the random colours. BTW, your `for` loop doesn't make sense. Neither `x` or `myguess` are changed inside the loop, so what's the point of doing the same test 5 times?

Answer (score 0):

You can shuffle elements by importing random, so let

```
import random
a = [1,2,3,4,5]
```

then you can say

```
print random.sample(a,2)
```

it will print

```
[4,2]
```

if you want a lot of random sets of numbers, then

```
z=[]
for i in range(3):
    z.append(random.sample(a,2))
```

now z will be like

```
[[3, 4], [1, 3], [7, 6]]
```

Hope this helps!